# how can i make flutter app when user make video call agora to user his phone will ringing

Tags: flutter, agora.io

i tried agora video call on my app but the problem is the next person phone not ringing . I tried to make next phone ringing like whatsapp using callkeep package put it not working

Answer (score 2):

To add call notification you will have to setup signalling which can be easily done via Agora RTM. And based on when the message is received is you can trigger the callkeep package to make the phone ring.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/faq/call_invite_notification

Comment: thanks bro but i am a flutter developer and the documentation talls me to use call keep package but it is very difficult to use
i am search for someone have a way to use it